# The package obdc is listed on CRAN-R but not available to install

Tags: r, cran

I'm trying to run MS SQL Server scrips in a R script and learning how to do this.

The way I found to be the the most complete is through DBI + obdc package.
And then the problem appear:
package ‘obdc’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)

I've checked and the obdc package is listed on CRAN-r.
How do I solve this kind of problem?

Bonus: Any tips on how do I know the most recent R-compatible version for a given package?
Bonus 2: I've tried to install the R 4.0.3 (released 10/10/20), but I couldn't even acess cran repository, I haven't a clue why. So I will be using R 4.0.2 for a little while till I try to update again.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are looking for the o-D-B-c package, not the the o-B-D-c package, the latter of which does not exist. Just use the correct spelling: `install.packages("odbc")` This just seems like a typo. Please avoid "bonus questions". If you have additional questions, post them separately with proper titles.

Comment: Good god, I'm feeling dumb now. Thank you, @MrFlick !